# How to create a redacted PDF where the redactions disappear with a password

Tags: passwords, pdf

I submit drawings of structures to clients. Sometimes the clients refuse to pay after I submit the drawings. Is there a way in which I can obscure parts of a PDF of the drawings and protect it using a password? After the client pays, I will provide the password and typing it will make the pdf clear.

Comment: Why go thru all that trouble? Produce 2 versions of the PDF; one obscured and a full one?

Comment: But is there a way to obscure the pdf and entering the password clears the obscured part of the pdf and make it readable

Comment: Using Adobe Acrobat? No. That's in their documentation. Your keyword is "redact"